# Jquery draggable: scrolling in droppable using helper 'clone' and appendTo

Tags: jquery-ui, clone, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable, appendto

I'm suing jquery ui draggable on a list of items that can be dropped on a .droppable list of other items. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4M7m/) to show what I'm trying to do:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left-pane" class="pane">
    <div class="item">Item A</div>
    <div class="item">Item B</div>
    <div class="item">Item C</div>
    <div class="item">Item D</div>
</div>

<div id="right-pane" class="pane">
    <div class="item">Item E</div>
    <div class="item">Item F</div>
    <div class="item">Item G</div>
    <div class="item">Item H</div>
</div>
```

​

```
$('.item').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: '#contentpane',
    cursor: 'move'
});
$('.item').droppable();
```

The panes have a fixed height, and `overflow-y: auto` so that we can scroll inside to see hidden elements.

When dragging an element from a list to the other, the lists do not scroll since I use appendTo and the dragged item is not in the list. Is there a way to make the list 'scrollable' when I drag an item over? otherwise it is not possible to drop the item at the bottom of the list, let's say drop 'Item A' on 'Item H' on the fiddle example

Comment: +1 for `appendTo`, I did not know about this property and it helped me HUGE with a project I am working on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only way I found to do it is to detect the position of the dragged element and scroll the droppable container, with a smooth effect so that it will scroll like doing it from the mouse wheel.

Comment: on which event you are detecting the position? 'drag'?

Answer (score 0):

Be able to use the scroll features from different container is really not easy to do.

I opended a topic on this subject. You will find an edit of the question with a functionnal workaround.
Check this related question : [JqueryUI, drag elements into cells of a scrolling dropable div containing large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670124/jqueryui-drag-elements-into-cells-of-a-scrolling-dropable-div-containing-large)

About your last remark, you could place your item at the boom of the list using the sortable property. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have another list that is sortable, but this one I don't want it to be sortable, which is why I only use droppable

Comment: your solution is not bad, but when dragging an element and trying to go down anywhere even outside of the drop zone ("#container"), the scroll happens in the drop zone which is kinda weird