# JQuery sortable when dragging item down below visible area, window does not scroll in firefox

Tags: firefox, jquery-ui-sortable

When using the jquery ui sortable widget and dragging an item down below the visible area in the browser, the window does not scroll so that you can drop it in an area below there where other items might be.  I haven't been able to find an answer to this for Firefox- I have seen a workaround for Chrome where you add a helper property to the sortable function that does the following:

```
helper: function (event, element) {
   return element.clone().appendTo('body');
}
```

...but again, this only fixes this same problem in Chrome, not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
helper: function(){
    $('yourScrollableContainer').append('<div id="clone">' + $(this).html() + '</div>');
    $("#clone").hide();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#clone').appendTo('body');
        $("#clone").show();
    },1);
    return $("#clone");
}
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14241994/jquery-ui-draggable-not-scrolling-the-sortable-container) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670124/jqueryui-drag-elements-into-cells-of-a-scrolling-dropable-div-containing-large) question for more help.